# Meaning of "exceeded by"

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when we say "the perimeter that is exceeded by 89% of parts". I searched everywhere, can't find the meaning of "exceeded by" phrase.

This was from an  [online exam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7W1I.jpg) that I solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're looking for the measurement of a perimeter where 89.2512% of the possible combinations have a larger perimeter.  In other words:

10.7488% of perimeters < p < 89.2512% of perimeters

Comment: Thank you so much. Another doubt, when we say "my score was exceeded by Alexa",  it means "Alexa scored more than me", and not  "Alexa helped me score more", right?

Comment: @User49582934 Yes, although it would be more common to say "My score was exceeded by Alexa's", and even more common to say "Alexa exceeded my score".  "Exceed" also relates to the adjective "excessive", as in "He drank excessive amounts of alcohol".

Answer (score 0):

So [exceed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exceed) means to *go beyond*. So since they're talking about [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics), they want you use the [standard deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) from the x and y [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) and using the [expected values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), a.k.a. *means*, and calculate the [perimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perimeter) that *goes beyond* or *exceeds* 89.2512%, implying there is only 1 correct answer;